# How to select columns created with unformatted names in pydatatable?

Tags: python, py-datatable

I have created a datatable as,

```
DT_EX = dt.Frame({'Year sold':[2000,2002,2004,2006],'Year Construction':[1990,1992,1994,1996]})
```

and its view as

```
Out[4]: 
   | Year sold  Year Construction
-- + ---------  -----------------
 0 |      2000               1990
 1 |      2002               1992
 2 |      2004               1994
 3 |      2006               1996

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

Here as we can notice that each column has contained a space between two words,

```
In [7]: DT_EX.names
```

```
Out[7]: ('Year sold', 'Year Construction')
```

I'm now selecting a first column as,

```
DT[:,f.Year sold]
```

It's throwing out an error

```
 File "<ipython-input-5-29b1f34a6dc6>", line 1
    DT[:,f.Year sold]
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Now i put some quotes around the column name and tried to select,

```
In [6]: DT[:,f.`Year sold`]
```

```
 File "<ipython-input-6-a007534b786e>", line 1
    DT[:,f.`Year sold`]
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So how to specify these kind of column names, i can do some string manipulations like adjusting space with underscrore _ Year_sold or Year_Construction etc etc.

Is there any option to in fread() to handle this type of column names when loading a dataset ?.

- Converting all  columns to eigther Lower or Upper case names
- Remove all the special symbols space between column names
- Shorten the column names length if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work :

```
In [1]: import datatable as dt                                                                                         

In [2]: DT_EX = dt.Frame({'Year sold':[2000,2002,2004,2006],'Year Construction':[1990,1992,1994,1996]})                

In [3]: DT_EX[:, dt.f['Year sold']]                                                                                    
Out[3]: 
   | Year sold
-- + ---------
 0 |      2000
 1 |      2002
 2 |      2004
 3 |      2006

[4 rows x 1 column]

In [4]:
```

using the `f` selector with brackets also allows selection using variables:

```
In [6]: feature = 'Year sold'                                                                                          

In [7]: DT_EX[:, dt.f[feature]]                                                                                        
Out[7]: 
   | Year sold
-- + ---------
 0 |      2000
 1 |      2002
 2 |      2004
 3 |      2006

[4 rows x 1 column]
```

Also if you want to replace spaces with underscores just do :

```
In [8]: DT_EX.names = [feat.replace(' ', '_') for feat in DT_EX.names]                                                 

In [9]: DT_EX                                                                                                          
Out[9]: 
   | Year_sold  Year_Construction
-- + ---------  -----------------
 0 |      2000               1990
 1 |      2002               1992
 2 |      2004               1994
 3 |      2006               1996

[4 rows x 2 columns]

In [10]:
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes makes sense, so in this case we are supposed to pass in the column names in list format. it would be nice if pydatable supports https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/ for cleaning some stuff.